# Как правильно закрыть экземпляр проводника через код Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал программу для личных нужд, код привел ниже, не могу взять в толк, каким образом убить процесс проводника если все проводники в Windows 7 с одним именем, можно было бы передать значение запуска проводника в переменную, и затем, как мне подсказывали ранее на этом сайте, через эту переменную и вычислить нужный процесс, выглядит это так `D = subprocess.Popen("explorer.exe D:")`,`D.kill()`, но дело в том, что на момент когда необходимо использовать `kill()`, переменная `D` еще не объявлена, или уже не объявлена, каким образом реализовать задуманное, с минимальными изменениями кода приведенного ниже?

```
import subprocess 
import webbrowser
import time
import os 


print('| Здравствуйте, вы решили поработать или закончили с делами? |')
# Проверка на правильность ввода данных, и реализация выбора пользователя
while True:
    Choice = input('| Закончить с делами [2]                                     |\
        \n| Поработать         [1]                                     |\n| Ввод: ')
    print('\n')
    if Choice.isnumeric():
        Choice = int(Choice) 
        break
    else:
        print('Пожалуйста введите номер варианта!')
        continue


# Список путей к программам, которые надо открыть
Opening1 = ['D:\\Program\\ShareX\\ShareX.exe',\
 'D:\\Miscellanea\\Programmig\\Programming-Python\\Книги\\Укус_Питона.pdf', \
 'D:\\Program\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe']

# Список адресов сайтов, которые надо открыть
Opening2 = ['https://ru.stackoverflow.com/',\
'https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru&sl=en&tl=ru&text=%0A&op=translate',\
'https://yandex.ru/search/?text=Python%203%20&lr=973&clid=1923018']

# Список процессов, которые необходимо завершить
Closing = ['ShareX.exe', 'PDFXCview.exe', 'notepad++.exe',]


def explorer():
    D = subprocess.Popen("explorer.exe D:")
    
# Выбор пользователя №1
if Choice == 1:
    # Открытие всех нужных сайтов
    for two in Opening2:
        webbrowser.open(two, 2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    # Открытие проводника 
    explorer()
    time.sleep(0.5)
        
    # Открытие всех нужных программ (кроме одной)
    for one in Opening1:
        subprocess.Popen(('start', one,),shell = True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    
# Выбор пользователя №2
elif Choice == 2:
    # Закрытие проводника
    D.kill()
    for Three in Closing:
        os.system('taskkill /pid Three')
        # Закрытие программы
        break
```